# Documents are stored in sharepoint

Tags: document-library

Where documents created in Document library are stored in Sharepoint? In database or file system.

Can we store documnets in file system??

Answer (score 1):

Files from Document library are stored in the SharePoint database by default, but you could configure file system storage using Remote Blob Storage. Check [this link](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/sharepoint-2010-storing-documents-on-the-file-system-with-remote-blob-storage/) to get more info.

Comment: if i configure like this, my documents won't be stored in database and it will be stored only in file system. right?

Comment: Yes, right. Follow "How to Enable the RBS FileStream Provider for SharePoint 2010" to do that.

Comment: If by default documents are stored in DB, then how can we view documents like a file system when we click Open in Explorer?

Comment: When we open document library in windows explorer view, SharePoint allows us to add/update/delete files as we do in the normal file system. But it is not mean that files are stored in a physical location on the disk.

Comment: It is not a separate file system. if we change in that file system, it gets reflected in DB also. How documents stored in DB are shown in explorer view?

Comment: On a default workstation installation, it will attempt to connect using SMB in addition to Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) and the FrontPage Server Extensions Remote Procedure Call (FPRPC) protocol. There is Microsoft official whitepaper that provides an overview of the Explorer View architecture: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9981 . Also, there is a short post about "Explorer view" here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx